# Problem in post man to convert into C# codes

Tags: c#, rest, post

I have a problem in POSTMAN parameters
I want to get a token from URL.
in postman parameters Body set to

`Json raw { "UserName": "xxx", "Password": "xxx" }`

and Method is POST

In PostMan it returns token ; but in c# by `Httpclient` I could not find how can do it

I tried code below:

```
        var client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("xxxx");


        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var url = "xxxx";

        var logonOptions = new
        {
            username = "xxx",
            password = "xxx",
        };

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var requestBodyAsString = serializer.Serialize(logonOptions);
        StringContent content =
            new StringContent(
                requestBodyAsString,
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/raw"
            );

        HttpResponseMessage response;
        string contributors="";
        try
        {
            response = await client.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            contributors = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(resp);
            
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Comment: "application/raw" and not "application/json"? Also, why are you using two different serializers?

Comment: I just testing to ways but not get any answers

Comment: Perhaps you could include the `resp` value in your question.